# Flutter analyze result on Jenkins

Tags: flutter, jenkins, static-analysis, warnings-next-generation

Is there a way to show the result of

```
flutter analyze
```

which is executed during a Jenkins build on the result page, like e.g. this graph for Android:

[image: static analysis android]

Can we use the Warnings-NG plugin with `recordIssues`-function? How to configure the function?

Comment: You can try to find plugins to do report formatting. Like this: https://github.com/WhisperArts/analyzer-formatter

Comment: Do you have an example on how to use it?

Comment: I'm support it. Right now it is just a local executable program. If you interested with it, I'm add manual in one-two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by configuring a custom Groovy Parser as described [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md#creating-a-new-tool-using-a-groovy-parser):

1. Goto Manage Jenkins -> System -> Section "Groovy Based Warnings Parsers"
2. Click on Add
3. Configure:

Name and ID are arbitrary values.
Regular Expression: `^\[(.*)\] (.*) \((.*):(\d*):(\d*)\)`
Mapping Script:

```
import edu.hm.hafner.analysis.Severity

String message = matcher.group(2)
String file = matcher.group(3)

return builder
    .setFileName(file)
    .setMessage(message)
    .setCategory("flutter")
    .setLineStart(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(4)))
    .setSeverity(Severity.WARNING_NORMAL) 
    .buildOptional();
```

Example Log Message:

```
[info] Missing a required trailing comma (/Users/user/Development/CICD/template-flutter/lib/main.dart:55:13)
[info] Missing a required trailing comma (/Users/user/Development/CICD/template-flutter/lib/main.dart:105:16)
```

Save the changes.

### Using the Groovy Parser:

In your `Jenkinsfile` add this for declarative pipelines:

```
stage('Static Analysis'){
    steps {
        sh label: 'flutter analyze', script: 'fvm flutter analyze --write=flutter_analyze_report.txt || true'
    }
    post {
        always {
            recordIssues(tools: [groovyScript(id: 'flutter-analyze', name: 'Flutter Analyze', parserId: '<the id you have configured in system settings>', pattern: '**/flutter_analyze_report.txt')])
        }
    }
}
```